# SCIP constraint not satisfied

Tags: scip, linear-optimization, scipopt

I am new to using SCIP, and I can't figure out why SCIP is not satisfying the constraints of my ILP. I have specified my ILP in the `.lp` format as described by IBM.

For example, consider the following constraints:

```
X0 - X1 - 5z_0_1_0 < 0
X1 - X0 - 5z_0_1_1 < 0
Y0 - Y1 - 5z_0_1_2 < 0
Y1 - Y0 - 5z_0_1_3 < 0
z_0_1_0 + z_0_1_1 + z_0_1_2 + z_0_1_3 <= 3
```

There are more constraints like this in my ILP, but I stick to these for my question.
I then solve the ILP containing the above constraints, where the constraints with `X` and `Y` are integer constraints defined under a `General` header as defined by IBM. The `z` constraints are binary.
I solve the ILP using `scip.exe>read>optimize`. The output is as follows:

```
SCIP> optimize

presolving:
(round 1, fast)       32 del vars, 32 del conss, 0 add conss, 0 chg bounds, 0 chg sides, 208 chg coeffs, 0 upgd conss, 0 impls, 8 clqs
   (0.0s) running MILP presolver
   (0.0s) MILP presolver found nothing
(round 2, exhaustive) 32 del vars, 32 del conss, 0 add conss, 0 chg bounds, 0 chg sides, 208 chg coeffs, 44 upgd conss, 0 impls, 8 clqs
   (0.0s) probing: 51/176 (29.0%) - 0 fixings, 0 aggregations, 0 implications, 0 bound changes
   (0.0s) probing aborted: 50/50 successive totally useless probings
   (0.0s) symmetry computation started: requiring (bin +, int -, cont +), (fixed: bin -, int +, cont -)
   (0.0s) no symmetry present
   (0.0s) symmetry computation started: requiring (bin +, int +, cont +), (fixed: bin -, int -, cont -)
   (0.0s) symmetry computation finished: 1 generators found (max: 1500, log10 of symmetry group size: 0.3)
(round 3, exhaustive) 32 del vars, 32 del conss, 1 add conss, 0 chg bounds, 0 chg sides, 208 chg coeffs, 44 upgd conss, 0 impls, 8 clqs
presolving (4 rounds: 4 fast, 3 medium, 3 exhaustive):
 32 deleted vars, 32 deleted constraints, 1 added constraints, 0 tightened bounds, 0 added holes, 0 changed sides, 208 changed coefficients
 0 implications, 8 cliques
presolved problem has 194 variables (176 bin, 18 int, 0 impl, 0 cont) and 285 constraints
      8 constraints of type <setppc>
    240 constraints of type <linear>
      1 constraints of type <orbitope>
     36 constraints of type <logicor>
transformed objective value is always integral (scale: 1)
Presolving Time: 0.00

 time | node  | left  |LP iter|LP it/n|mem/heur|mdpt |vars |cons |rows |cuts |sepa|confs|strbr|  dualbound   | primalbound  |  gap   | compl.
p 0.0s|     1 |     0 |     0 |     - |   locks|   0 | 194 | 285 | 284 |   0 |  0 |   0 |   0 | 8.000000e+00 | 2.000000e+00 | 300.00%| unknown
* 0.0s|     1 |     0 |    24 |     - |    LP  |   0 | 194 | 285 | 284 |   0 |  0 |   0 |   0 | 8.000000e+00 | 8.000000e+00 |   0.00%| unknown
  0.0s|     1 |     0 |    24 |     - |  4594k |   0 | 194 | 285 | 284 |   0 |  0 |   0 |   0 | 8.000000e+00 | 8.000000e+00 |   0.00%| unknown

SCIP Status        : problem is solved [optimal solution found]
Solving Time (sec) : 0.00
Solving Nodes      : 1
Primal Bound       : +8.00000000000000e+00 (2 solutions)
Dual Bound         : +8.00000000000000e+00
Gap                : 0.00 %
```

If I then inspect the values relevant to the above constraint I see the following:

```
SCIP> display value X0
X0                                                  0   (obj:0)
SCIP> display value X1
X1                                                  0   (obj:0)
SCIP> display value Y0
Y0                                                  0   (obj:0)
SCIP> display value Y1
Y1                                                  0   (obj:0)
SCIP> display value z_0_1_0
z_0_1_0                                             0   (obj:0)
SCIP> display value z_0_1_1
z_0_1_1                                             0   (obj:0)
SCIP> display value z_0_1_2 
z_0_1_2                                             0   (obj:0)
SCIP> display value z_0_1_3
z_0_1_3                                             0   (obj:0)
```

As you can see, with these variable values the constraints above are literally not satisfied? Am I missing some setting or notation that's easy to miss from the documentation? I have tried varying the multiplication notation with a space but that does not help.

The entire `.lp` file is as follows:

```
Maximize
obj: F0u + F1u + F2r + F3r + F4d + F5d + F6l + F7l
Subject To
X0 - X1 - 5z_0_1_0 < 0
X1 - X0 - 5z_0_1_1 < 0
Y0 - Y1 - 5z_0_1_2 < 0
Y1 - Y0 - 5z_0_1_3 < 0
z_0_1_0 + z_0_1_1 + z_0_1_2 + z_0_1_3 <= 3
X0 - X2 - 5z_0_2_0 < 0
X2 - X0 - 5z_0_2_1 < 0
Y0 - Y2 - 5z_0_2_2 < 0
Y2 - Y0 - 5z_0_2_3 < 0
z_0_2_0 + z_0_2_1 + z_0_2_2 + z_0_2_3 <= 3
X0 - X3 - 5z_0_3_0 < 0
X3 - X0 - 5z_0_3_1 < 0
Y0 - Y3 - 5z_0_3_2 < 0
Y3 - Y0 - 5z_0_3_3 < 0
z_0_3_0 + z_0_3_1 + z_0_3_2 + z_0_3_3 <= 3
X0 - X4 - 5z_0_4_0 < 0
X4 - X0 - 5z_0_4_1 < 0
Y0 - Y4 - 5z_0_4_2 < 0
Y4 - Y0 - 5z_0_4_3 < 0
z_0_4_0 + z_0_4_1 + z_0_4_2 + z_0_4_3 <= 3
X0 - X5 - 5z_0_5_0 < 0
X5 - X0 - 5z_0_5_1 < 0
Y0 - Y5 - 5z_0_5_2 < 0
Y5 - Y0 - 5z_0_5_3 < 0
z_0_5_0 + z_0_5_1 + z_0_5_2 + z_0_5_3 <= 3
X0 - X6 - 5z_0_6_0 < 0
X6 - X0 - 5z_0_6_1 < 0
Y0 - Y6 - 5z_0_6_2 < 0
Y6 - Y0 - 5z_0_6_3 < 0
z_0_6_0 + z_0_6_1 + z_0_6_2 + z_0_6_3 <= 3
X0 - X7 - 5z_0_7_0 < 0
X7 - X0 - 5z_0_7_1 < 0
Y0 - Y7 - 5z_0_7_2 < 0
Y7 - Y0 - 5z_0_7_3 < 0
z_0_7_0 + z_0_7_1 + z_0_7_2 + z_0_7_3 <= 3
X0 - X8 - 5z_0_8_0 < 0
X8 - X0 - 5z_0_8_1 < 0
Y0 - Y8 - 5z_0_8_2 < 0
Y8 - Y0 - 5z_0_8_3 < 0
z_0_8_0 + z_0_8_1 + z_0_8_2 + z_0_8_3 <= 3
X1 - X2 - 5z_1_2_0 < 0
X2 - X1 - 5z_1_2_1 < 0
Y1 - Y2 - 5z_1_2_2 < 0
Y2 - Y1 - 5z_1_2_3 < 0
z_1_2_0 + z_1_2_1 + z_1_2_2 + z_1_2_3 <= 3
X1 - X3 - 5z_1_3_0 < 0
X3 - X1 - 5z_1_3_1 < 0
Y1 - Y3 - 5z_1_3_2 < 0
Y3 - Y1 - 5z_1_3_3 < 0
z_1_3_0 + z_1_3_1 + z_1_3_2 + z_1_3_3 <= 3
X1 - X4 - 5z_1_4_0 < 0
X4 - X1 - 5z_1_4_1 < 0
Y1 - Y4 - 5z_1_4_2 < 0
Y4 - Y1 - 5z_1_4_3 < 0
z_1_4_0 + z_1_4_1 + z_1_4_2 + z_1_4_3 <= 3
X1 - X5 - 5z_1_5_0 < 0
X5 - X1 - 5z_1_5_1 < 0
Y1 - Y5 - 5z_1_5_2 < 0
Y5 - Y1 - 5z_1_5_3 < 0
z_1_5_0 + z_1_5_1 + z_1_5_2 + z_1_5_3 <= 3
X1 - X6 - 5z_1_6_0 < 0
X6 - X1 - 5z_1_6_1 < 0
Y1 - Y6 - 5z_1_6_2 < 0
Y6 - Y1 - 5z_1_6_3 < 0
z_1_6_0 + z_1_6_1 + z_1_6_2 + z_1_6_3 <= 3
X1 - X7 - 5z_1_7_0 < 0
X7 - X1 - 5z_1_7_1 < 0
Y1 - Y7 - 5z_1_7_2 < 0
Y7 - Y1 - 5z_1_7_3 < 0
z_1_7_0 + z_1_7_1 + z_1_7_2 + z_1_7_3 <= 3
X1 - X8 - 5z_1_8_0 < 0
X8 - X1 - 5z_1_8_1 < 0
Y1 - Y8 - 5z_1_8_2 < 0
Y8 - Y1 - 5z_1_8_3 < 0
z_1_8_0 + z_1_8_1 + z_1_8_2 + z_1_8_3 <= 3
X2 - X3 - 5z_2_3_0 < 0
X3 - X2 - 5z_2_3_1 < 0
Y2 - Y3 - 5z_2_3_2 < 0
Y3 - Y2 - 5z_2_3_3 < 0
z_2_3_0 + z_2_3_1 + z_2_3_2 + z_2_3_3 <= 3
X2 - X4 - 5z_2_4_0 < 0
X4 - X2 - 5z_2_4_1 < 0
Y2 - Y4 - 5z_2_4_2 < 0
Y4 - Y2 - 5z_2_4_3 < 0
z_2_4_0 + z_2_4_1 + z_2_4_2 + z_2_4_3 <= 3
X2 - X5 - 5z_2_5_0 < 0
X5 - X2 - 5z_2_5_1 < 0
Y2 - Y5 - 5z_2_5_2 < 0
Y5 - Y2 - 5z_2_5_3 < 0
z_2_5_0 + z_2_5_1 + z_2_5_2 + z_2_5_3 <= 3
X2 - X6 - 5z_2_6_0 < 0
X6 - X2 - 5z_2_6_1 < 0
Y2 - Y6 - 5z_2_6_2 < 0
Y6 - Y2 - 5z_2_6_3 < 0
z_2_6_0 + z_2_6_1 + z_2_6_2 + z_2_6_3 <= 3
X2 - X7 - 5z_2_7_0 < 0
X7 - X2 - 5z_2_7_1 < 0
Y2 - Y7 - 5z_2_7_2 < 0
Y7 - Y2 - 5z_2_7_3 < 0
z_2_7_0 + z_2_7_1 + z_2_7_2 + z_2_7_3 <= 3
X2 - X8 - 5z_2_8_0 < 0
X8 - X2 - 5z_2_8_1 < 0
Y2 - Y8 - 5z_2_8_2 < 0
Y8 - Y2 - 5z_2_8_3 < 0
z_2_8_0 + z_2_8_1 + z_2_8_2 + z_2_8_3 <= 3
X3 - X4 - 5z_3_4_0 < 0
X4 - X3 - 5z_3_4_1 < 0
Y3 - Y4 - 5z_3_4_2 < 0
Y4 - Y3 - 5z_3_4_3 < 0
z_3_4_0 + z_3_4_1 + z_3_4_2 + z_3_4_3 <= 3
X3 - X5 - 5z_3_5_0 < 0
X5 - X3 - 5z_3_5_1 < 0
Y3 - Y5 - 5z_3_5_2 < 0
Y5 - Y3 - 5z_3_5_3 < 0
z_3_5_0 + z_3_5_1 + z_3_5_2 + z_3_5_3 <= 3
X3 - X6 - 5z_3_6_0 < 0
X6 - X3 - 5z_3_6_1 < 0
Y3 - Y6 - 5z_3_6_2 < 0
Y6 - Y3 - 5z_3_6_3 < 0
z_3_6_0 + z_3_6_1 + z_3_6_2 + z_3_6_3 <= 3
X3 - X7 - 5z_3_7_0 < 0
X7 - X3 - 5z_3_7_1 < 0
Y3 - Y7 - 5z_3_7_2 < 0
Y7 - Y3 - 5z_3_7_3 < 0
z_3_7_0 + z_3_7_1 + z_3_7_2 + z_3_7_3 <= 3
X3 - X8 - 5z_3_8_0 < 0
X8 - X3 - 5z_3_8_1 < 0
Y3 - Y8 - 5z_3_8_2 < 0
Y8 - Y3 - 5z_3_8_3 < 0
z_3_8_0 + z_3_8_1 + z_3_8_2 + z_3_8_3 <= 3
X4 - X5 - 5z_4_5_0 < 0
X5 - X4 - 5z_4_5_1 < 0
Y4 - Y5 - 5z_4_5_2 < 0
Y5 - Y4 - 5z_4_5_3 < 0
z_4_5_0 + z_4_5_1 + z_4_5_2 + z_4_5_3 <= 3
X4 - X6 - 5z_4_6_0 < 0
X6 - X4 - 5z_4_6_1 < 0
Y4 - Y6 - 5z_4_6_2 < 0
Y6 - Y4 - 5z_4_6_3 < 0
z_4_6_0 + z_4_6_1 + z_4_6_2 + z_4_6_3 <= 3
X4 - X7 - 5z_4_7_0 < 0
X7 - X4 - 5z_4_7_1 < 0
Y4 - Y7 - 5z_4_7_2 < 0
Y7 - Y4 - 5z_4_7_3 < 0
z_4_7_0 + z_4_7_1 + z_4_7_2 + z_4_7_3 <= 3
X4 - X8 - 5z_4_8_0 < 0
X8 - X4 - 5z_4_8_1 < 0
Y4 - Y8 - 5z_4_8_2 < 0
Y8 - Y4 - 5z_4_8_3 < 0
z_4_8_0 + z_4_8_1 + z_4_8_2 + z_4_8_3 <= 3
X5 - X6 - 5z_5_6_0 < 0
X6 - X5 - 5z_5_6_1 < 0
Y5 - Y6 - 5z_5_6_2 < 0
Y6 - Y5 - 5z_5_6_3 < 0
z_5_6_0 + z_5_6_1 + z_5_6_2 + z_5_6_3 <= 3
X5 - X7 - 5z_5_7_0 < 0
X7 - X5 - 5z_5_7_1 < 0
Y5 - Y7 - 5z_5_7_2 < 0
Y7 - Y5 - 5z_5_7_3 < 0
z_5_7_0 + z_5_7_1 + z_5_7_2 + z_5_7_3 <= 3
X5 - X8 - 5z_5_8_0 < 0
X8 - X5 - 5z_5_8_1 < 0
Y5 - Y8 - 5z_5_8_2 < 0
Y8 - Y5 - 5z_5_8_3 < 0
z_5_8_0 + z_5_8_1 + z_5_8_2 + z_5_8_3 <= 3
X6 - X7 - 5z_6_7_0 < 0
X7 - X6 - 5z_6_7_1 < 0
Y6 - Y7 - 5z_6_7_2 < 0
Y7 - Y6 - 5z_6_7_3 < 0
z_6_7_0 + z_6_7_1 + z_6_7_2 + z_6_7_3 <= 3
X6 - X8 - 5z_6_8_0 < 0
X8 - X6 - 5z_6_8_1 < 0
Y6 - Y8 - 5z_6_8_2 < 0
Y8 - Y6 - 5z_6_8_3 < 0
z_6_8_0 + z_6_8_1 + z_6_8_2 + z_6_8_3 <= 3
X7 - X8 - 5z_7_8_0 < 0
X8 - X7 - 5z_7_8_1 < 0
Y7 - Y8 - 5z_7_8_2 < 0
Y8 - Y7 - 5z_7_8_3 < 0
z_7_8_0 + z_7_8_1 + z_7_8_2 + z_7_8_3 <= 3
F0u - Y1 + Y0 >= 0
F0u + nF0u = 1
X0 - X1 - 5nF0u <= 0
X1 - X0 - 5nF0u <= 0
F0d - Y0 + Y1 >= 0
F0d + nF0d = 1
X0 - X1 - 5nF0d <= 0
X1 - X0 - 5nF0d <= 0
F0l - X0 + X1 >= 0
F0l + nF0l = 1
Y0 - Y1 - 5nF0l <= 0
Y1 - Y0 - 5nF0l <= 0
F0r - X1 + X0 >= 0
F0r + nF0r = 1
Y0 - Y1 - 5nF0r <= 0
Y1 - Y0 - 5nF0r <= 0
F0u + F0d + F0l + F0r = 1
F1u - Y2 + Y1 >= 0
F1u + nF1u = 1
X1 - X2 - 5nF1u <= 0
X2 - X1 - 5nF1u <= 0
F1d - Y1 + Y2 >= 0
F1d + nF1d = 1
X1 - X2 - 5nF1d <= 0
X2 - X1 - 5nF1d <= 0
F1l - X1 + X2 >= 0
F1l + nF1l = 1
Y1 - Y2 - 5nF1l <= 0
Y2 - Y1 - 5nF1l <= 0
F1r - X2 + X1 >= 0
F1r + nF1r = 1
Y1 - Y2 - 5nF1r <= 0
Y2 - Y1 - 5nF1r <= 0
F1u + F1d + F1l + F1r = 1
F2u - Y3 + Y2 >= 0
F2u + nF2u = 1
X2 - X3 - 5nF2u <= 0
X3 - X2 - 5nF2u <= 0
F2d - Y2 + Y3 >= 0
F2d + nF2d = 1
X2 - X3 - 5nF2d <= 0
X3 - X2 - 5nF2d <= 0
F2l - X2 + X3 >= 0
F2l + nF2l = 1
Y2 - Y3 - 5nF2l <= 0
Y3 - Y2 - 5nF2l <= 0
F2r - X3 + X2 >= 0
F2r + nF2r = 1
Y2 - Y3 - 5nF2r <= 0
Y3 - Y2 - 5nF2r <= 0
F2u + F2d + F2l + F2r = 1
F3u - Y4 + Y3 >= 0
F3u + nF3u = 1
X3 - X4 - 5nF3u <= 0
X4 - X3 - 5nF3u <= 0
F3d - Y3 + Y4 >= 0
F3d + nF3d = 1
X3 - X4 - 5nF3d <= 0
X4 - X3 - 5nF3d <= 0
F3l - X3 + X4 >= 0
F3l + nF3l = 1
Y3 - Y4 - 5nF3l <= 0
Y4 - Y3 - 5nF3l <= 0
F3r - X4 + X3 >= 0
F3r + nF3r = 1
Y3 - Y4 - 5nF3r <= 0
Y4 - Y3 - 5nF3r <= 0
F3u + F3d + F3l + F3r = 1
F4u - Y5 + Y4 >= 0
F4u + nF4u = 1
X4 - X5 - 5nF4u <= 0
X5 - X4 - 5nF4u <= 0
F4d - Y4 + Y5 >= 0
F4d + nF4d = 1
X4 - X5 - 5nF4d <= 0
X5 - X4 - 5nF4d <= 0
F4l - X4 + X5 >= 0
F4l + nF4l = 1
Y4 - Y5 - 5nF4l <= 0
Y5 - Y4 - 5nF4l <= 0
F4r - X5 + X4 >= 0
F4r + nF4r = 1
Y4 - Y5 - 5nF4r <= 0
Y5 - Y4 - 5nF4r <= 0
F4u + F4d + F4l + F4r = 1
F5u - Y6 + Y5 >= 0
F5u + nF5u = 1
X5 - X6 - 5nF5u <= 0
X6 - X5 - 5nF5u <= 0
F5d - Y5 + Y6 >= 0
F5d + nF5d = 1
X5 - X6 - 5nF5d <= 0
X6 - X5 - 5nF5d <= 0
F5l - X5 + X6 >= 0
F5l + nF5l = 1
Y5 - Y6 - 5nF5l <= 0
Y6 - Y5 - 5nF5l <= 0
F5r - X6 + X5 >= 0
F5r + nF5r = 1
Y5 - Y6 - 5nF5r <= 0
Y6 - Y5 - 5nF5r <= 0
F5u + F5d + F5l + F5r = 1
F6u - Y7 + Y6 >= 0
F6u + nF6u = 1
X6 - X7 - 5nF6u <= 0
X7 - X6 - 5nF6u <= 0
F6d - Y6 + Y7 >= 0
F6d + nF6d = 1
X6 - X7 - 5nF6d <= 0
X7 - X6 - 5nF6d <= 0
F6l - X6 + X7 >= 0
F6l + nF6l = 1
Y6 - Y7 - 5nF6l <= 0
Y7 - Y6 - 5nF6l <= 0
F6r - X7 + X6 >= 0
F6r + nF6r = 1
Y6 - Y7 - 5nF6r <= 0
Y7 - Y6 - 5nF6r <= 0
F6u + F6d + F6l + F6r = 1
F7u - Y8 + Y7 >= 0
F7u + nF7u = 1
X7 - X8 - 5nF7u <= 0
X8 - X7 - 5nF7u <= 0
F7d - Y7 + Y8 >= 0
F7d + nF7d = 1
X7 - X8 - 5nF7d <= 0
X8 - X7 - 5nF7d <= 0
F7l - X7 + X8 >= 0
F7l + nF7l = 1
Y7 - Y8 - 5nF7l <= 0
Y8 - Y7 - 5nF7l <= 0
F7r - X8 + X7 >= 0
F7r + nF7r = 1
Y7 - Y8 - 5nF7r <= 0
Y8 - Y7 - 5nF7r <= 0
F7u + F7d + F7l + F7r = 1
Bounds
0 <= X0 <= 4
0 <= Y0 <= 4
0 <= X1 <= 4
0 <= Y1 <= 4
0 <= X2 <= 4
0 <= Y2 <= 4
0 <= X3 <= 4
0 <= Y3 <= 4
0 <= X4 <= 4
0 <= Y4 <= 4
0 <= X5 <= 4
0 <= Y5 <= 4
0 <= X6 <= 4
0 <= Y6 <= 4
0 <= X7 <= 4
0 <= Y7 <= 4
0 <= X8 <= 4
0 <= Y8 <= 4
General
X0 Y0 X1 Y1 X2 Y2 X3 Y3 X4 Y4 X5 Y5 X6 Y6 X7 Y7 X8 Y8
Binary
F0u F0d F0l F0r F1u F1d F1l F1r F2u F2d F2l F2r F3u F3d F3l F3r F4u F4d F4l F4r F5u F5d F5l F5r F6u F6d F6l F6r F7u F7d F7l F7r z_0_1_0 z_0_1_1 z_0_1_2 z_0_1_3 z_0_2_0 z_0_2_1 z_0_2_2 z_0_2_3 z_0_3_0 z_0_3_1 z_0_3_2 z_0_3_3 z_0_4_0 z_0_4_1 z_0_4_2 z_0_4_3 z_0_5_0 z_0_5_1 z_0_5_2 z_0_5_3 z_0_6_0 z_0_6_1 z_0_6_2 z_0_6_3 z_0_7_0 z_0_7_1 z_0_7_2 z_0_7_3 z_0_8_0 z_0_8_1 z_0_8_2 z_0_8_3 z_1_2_0 z_1_2_1 z_1_2_2 z_1_2_3 z_1_3_0 z_1_3_1 z_1_3_2 z_1_3_3 z_1_4_0 z_1_4_1 z_1_4_2 z_1_4_3 z_1_5_0 z_1_5_1 z_1_5_2 z_1_5_3 z_1_6_0 z_1_6_1 z_1_6_2 z_1_6_3 z_1_7_0 z_1_7_1 z_1_7_2 z_1_7_3 z_1_8_0 z_1_8_1 z_1_8_2 z_1_8_3 z_2_3_0 z_2_3_1 z_2_3_2 z_2_3_3 z_2_4_0 z_2_4_1 z_2_4_2 z_2_4_3 z_2_5_0 z_2_5_1 z_2_5_2 z_2_5_3 z_2_6_0 z_2_6_1 z_2_6_2 z_2_6_3 z_2_7_0 z_2_7_1 z_2_7_2 z_2_7_3 z_2_8_0 z_2_8_1 z_2_8_2 z_2_8_3 z_3_4_0 z_3_4_1 z_3_4_2 z_3_4_3 z_3_5_0 z_3_5_1 z_3_5_2 z_3_5_3 z_3_6_0 z_3_6_1 z_3_6_2 z_3_6_3 z_3_7_0 z_3_7_1 z_3_7_2 z_3_7_3 z_3_8_0 z_3_8_1 z_3_8_2 z_3_8_3 z_4_5_0 z_4_5_1 z_4_5_2 z_4_5_3 z_4_6_0 z_4_6_1 z_4_6_2 z_4_6_3 z_4_7_0 z_4_7_1 z_4_7_2 z_4_7_3 z_4_8_0 z_4_8_1 z_4_8_2 z_4_8_3 z_5_6_0 z_5_6_1 z_5_6_2 z_5_6_3 z_5_7_0 z_5_7_1 z_5_7_2 z_5_7_3 z_5_8_0 z_5_8_1 z_5_8_2 z_5_8_3 z_6_7_0 z_6_7_1 z_6_7_2 z_6_7_3 z_6_8_0 z_6_8_1 z_6_8_2 z_6_8_3 z_7_8_0 z_7_8_1 z_7_8_2 z_7_8_3 nF0u nF0d nF0l nF0r nF1u nF1d nF1l nF1r nF2u nF2d nF2l nF2r nF3u nF3d nF3l nF3r nF4u nF4d nF4l nF4r nF5u nF5d nF5l nF5r nF6u nF6d nF6l nF6r nF7u nF7d nF7l nF7r
End
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry this question has been looked over. The LP file format does not recognize strict inequalities and instead will transfer all your `<` constraints into `<=`. If your model only has binary variables this may be easily fixable by swapping `< 0` for `<= -1`.

In the continuous case you may need to convert `< 0 into <= -eps` with a small epsilon (note that this can cause numerical issues).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I figured that out myself by just randomly changing stuff to see if I could make it work. It's funny how IBM chooses to state that, they state it in a way such that it is REALLY easy to read over the fact that < gets changed to <=: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/12.9.0?topic=representation-constraints-in-lp-file-format